# Слушатель на изменение переменной

Tags: android

Как установить слушатель на изменение переменной, к примеру, глобальной?

Comment: Никак. Это невозможно.

Comment: Если эта переменная "Ваша", тогда нет проблем - делаете класс, в который все заворачиваете, правите код по надобности и готово.

Comment: @KoVadim - "Моя" переменная станет полем создаваемого класса? В создаваемом классе  прописать слушатель на неё?

Comment: без контретного кода ответить не могу.